# Ducky One2 SF not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: usb, 22.04, keyboard

I have a Ducky One2 SF that is connected to my laptop (ThinkPad X1 Carbon) running Ubuntu 22.04 with USB. The keyboard's RGB seem to be working fine, so it IS drawing power, but none of the keystrokes are registering.

The `lsusb` output looks as follows:

`Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0416:0123 Winbond Electronics Corp. Ducky One2 SF RGB`

And the `lsusb` tree is as follows:

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

So I can see that the Ducky keyboard is registering itself as a USB HID device, although I'm not sure why it needs 4 interfaces.

I also tried to check if somehow the input through this keyboard got disabled, so I looked at `xinput`, and here's what I find (not disabled/floating)

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3289-021                      id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB                   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB                   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB                   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB                   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Here's the `dmesg` logs:

```
[    1.746243] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[    1.746245] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[    2.795697] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.0001/input/input6
[    2.854924] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[    2.855108] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.0002/input/input7
[    2.855284] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[    2.855428] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.0003/input/input8
[    2.915165] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[    2.915499] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.0004/input/input9
[    2.975090] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[   10.780651] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[   10.780657] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[   10.785213] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.0005/input/input10
[   10.847161] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[   10.849419] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.0006/input/input11
[   10.850176] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0006: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[   10.850967] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.0007/input/input12
[   10.911405] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0007: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[   10.913528] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.0008/input/input13
[   10.971447] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0008: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 1542.526282] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[ 1542.526287] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[ 1542.531187] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.0009/input/input24
[ 1542.589169] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 1542.591503] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.000A/input/input25
[ 1542.592353] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[ 1542.594022] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.000B/input/input26
[ 1542.652811] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.000B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[ 1542.654851] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.000C/input/input27
[ 1542.712669] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.000C: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 3886.825573] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[ 3886.825576] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[ 3886.828713] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.000E/input/input29
[ 3886.892223] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.000E: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 3886.893220] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.000F/input/input30
[ 3886.893554] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.000F: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[ 3886.894406] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.0010/input/input31
[ 3886.952592] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0010: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[ 3886.953885] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.0011/input/input32
[ 3887.012950] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0011: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 3894.394283] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[ 3894.394288] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[ 3894.398357] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.0012/input/input33
[ 3894.457273] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0012: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 3894.459305] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.0013/input/input34
[ 3894.460032] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0013: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[ 3894.461976] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.0014/input/input35
[ 3894.520707] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0014: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[ 3894.522535] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.0015/input/input36
[ 3894.580519] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0015: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 3899.793731] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[ 3899.793739] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[ 3899.800530] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.0016/input/input37
[ 3899.860621] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0016: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 3899.862604] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.0017/input/input38
[ 3899.863424] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0017: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[ 3899.865391] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.0018/input/input39
[ 3899.924431] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0018: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[ 3899.926363] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.0019/input/input40
[ 3899.984315] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.0019: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 3902.865539] usb 1-1: Product: Ducky One2 SF RGB
[ 3902.865541] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Ducky
[ 3902.868530] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0416:0123.001A/input/input41
[ 3902.928813] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.001A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 3902.930751] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:0416:0123.001B/input/input42
[ 3902.931577] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.001B: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[ 3902.933627] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:0416:0123.001C/input/input43
[ 3902.992607] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.001C: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[ 3902.994456] input: Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:0416:0123.001D/input/input44
[ 3903.052543] hid-generic 0003:0416:0123.001D: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [Ducky Ducky One2 SF RGB] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
```

I don't see any issues here either.

At this point I am not sure how to debug further and what might be up here. Any clues?

Edit:

I tested with `evtest`, and did not see any events registered on any of the 4 interfaces.